# Careers features and multi account abuse concerns

Tags: discussion

I have been reading about all the benefits of the Careers to potential employers finding candidates. Normally I would be very excited to see this but I recently had a bad experience on SO where I felt the need to make a complaint against the person. A moderator got involved, but did little (this is his decision and I respect that).

My concern is, now that SO is making all this data available about reputation to potential employers looking for candidates. My rep (small as it may be) actually means something, as it has the potential to remove me from consideration for certain jobs simply based on the tags I use and the strength of my posts under those tags.

As per my previous problem, a person with a lot of reputation on 2 accounts voted my question down with both accounts, voted to close my question, and ordered me around as if he owned the site. I pointed out the two accounts to a moderator as I felt it was abusive. He obviously agreed as he removed the close votes and the comments made. But as far as I know did nothing about the 2 accounts. Again his decision and I respect that.

My issue is, that with people using multiple accounts to up vote their own questions, down vote others, and cast multiple close votes, this is clear abuse of the system. Until this is dealt with in a way that gives people the ability to combine such accounts into one with all the consequences that entails, I don't believe SO should be using reputation and tag information to determine suitability for careers.

Before, reputation was just a number. 5 points here, 5 there. Who cares. But now that number potentially affects peoples careers. So until there is a way to deal with abuse of the system, such information is unreliable at best and completely unfair and open to abuse, and should not be used.

After seeing what happened to this person, I taught, why not have multiple accounts myself. The only thing that stopped me is that my reputation did not have any real impact outside of SO. I cant go to the bank with 1000 points and ask for $100 in exchange. But now it does have a real impact, and that can be potentially extremely damaging.

Given that, I am seriously considering opening 20 accounts (why stop at 2)? If others have an unfair edge over me because of multi account abuse, and bad practice, and nothing gets done about it. As they say, since you can't beat them, join them.

**While I wont be setting up alternate accounts just yet (I probably would if only I had the time to manage them, as it takes me most of my spare time to manage my single one), I would like to know what others feel about this. Remember, now S/O can really affect your career, and you have no protection against abuse as the system stands. Your rating and your tags are no longer just numbers.**

Comment: *Ratings and tags are no longer just numbers*. Yes! They measure how good people are [playing this game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_addiction_disorder).

Comment: Socks that engage in targeted voting the way you describe are voting rings, which are generally dealt with rather harshly, including the deletion of all but one account (if that), and reversal of the fraudulent votes. If an account didn't get deleted, there probably wasn't enough evidence to be sure it was actually part of a ring. (Yet.)

Comment: If a hiring manager looks at my 2500 points of SO reputation and says, "this person cannot possibly be a lead programmer" without looking at my 15 years of experience in the field, I say, "good riddance". But that's me.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - That's a fair point. But unlike you I don't have anything close to 15 years of experience to fall back on, so my little profile actually ads a lot of strength to my career, and the work I do on SO is something I both enjoy and use actively in my career when looking for new opportunities.

Comment: And conversely, if someone sees that a user has 50,000 rep on SO, but in looking at the questions sees that they're all crap posts that don't demonstrate a strong knowledge of the material (but have a high score purely from voting fraud) then they're not going to hire you.  Anyone who would is, again, not somewhere you'd want to work.

Answer (score 10):

A few comments here: your flags were accepted as a result of the argumentative comments being removed. That does not mean that we found any evidence that a user was conspiring against you with multiple accounts. I just looked at this, and I see no coordinated voting involving this user.

The people who voted to close your post came from completely different parts of the world, and were clearly distinct users. The close votes on your post were not removed by moderators (we don't have the ability to nullify votes), but as a result of [community review voting to leave the question open](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10082302).

In this case, you were not the subject of attack from sock puppet accounts. In fact, we rarely see sock puppet accounts used to attack other people. Usually, they are just used to vote for a central account, and most of those cases seem to be motivated by trying to evade a question ban.

We have very good tools for hunting down sock puppet accounts, and the community also has a good eye for spotting anomalous voting behavior. If you're thinking of using sock puppet accounts to boost your profile for the sake of career opportunities, that probably won't work out well for you. If caught, we'll delete the sock puppet accounts, nullify all the votes they cast, and usually suspend your account for a long time.

How would it look to an employer to see your account on Stack Overflow suspended for voting irregularities?

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to see the reasons why flags are removed or other reasons for decisions made by the moderator or community. So I am unable to comment on your first point as I can only assume you have access to parts of the system I do not due to your reputation or other status. So I will respect your opinion on this.

Comment: I certainty disagree on what you say in the second paragraph as there is definitely some confusion here. I have not mentioned or linked to the place this happened as I do not feel the moderator did anything wrong. I compared both accounts and the 2 profiles I pointed out in my complaint (which I also did not mention here) were in fact from not only the same part of the world, but the same city and there was considerably more than this single fact considered into my accusation.

Comment: I was very careful to do my research on this before making the complaint as I do not like to waste mine or other peoples time without facts. So the second point you made must obviously be referring to a different flag or issue somewhere as I had enough facts to be certain the two accounts were the same person. Obviously the moderator did not feel the same, but as mentioned, I both accept and respect his decision on this. However, I disagree with you saying they were from different cities, there simply must be some confusion there as I made certain to do my research beforehand. Sorry.

Comment: I cannot comment on the 3rd paragraph. Again given you have more reputation and experience on the site I assume once again you know and have access to information I do not which allows you to make such open comments. So I bow to your knowledge and onion on these matters.

Comment: I don't understand your remaining points. Puppet accounts have been commented on many times here on meta, so obviously a lot of people are abusing them and little is done. Which is very contrary to what you say. Also, I said I was only thinking about doing it. I don't understand how with over 4 years on S/O I have less than 2K rep, while people with only 3 years have in excess of 20K. I am fairly active on S/O and the only way I could be more active is if I give up my day job and even at that, I'd have better things to do than pick around with multiple accounts in order to bolster my rep.

Comment: Finally - I hope my comments don't come across as disrespectful. This is not my intention. So apologies in advance if that is how it seems. I was just worried mostly about the second paragraph, as I am quite certain there must be some confusion there.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers - You might not be aware of this, but the diamond after my name indicates that I'm [one of the elected moderators of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). As such, I can see a *lot* more information about users than normal members can. I also can see every flag that you have cast, so I know exactly the posts you're talking about. I also speak from experience about hunting down sock puppet accounts, because that's part of my job here (ask around and you'll find that I've dealt with a lot of them). Only a very tiny fraction of users ever attempt sock puppets.

Comment: I did not know you were a moderator or that this is what the diamond means. Thanks for your answer. I accept that as you have access to more information than I given your status, you can make as many claims as you like. So I must bow to your knowledge in regard to all BUT the second paragraph. I did my research on the user I accused of being a puppet and the two accounts were the same city and as mentioned there was much more than this simple fact considered. So, with all due respect, I do not accept you are correct on the second point, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Some of the other considerations made around said puppet user were that the 2 accounts were started at the same time (around 3 years ago). Within a matter of minutes these close votes appeared as did votes on his own replies, along with the fact that one account was all answers while the other was almost all questions and they were all in the same subject areas. There were also several places where both accounts commented and voted up each other. So sorry, the moderator may not choose to agree these are the same person, and while I have to respect this, I don't have to agree.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that employers do look at SO profiles when they evaluate candidates. **However, your total reputation is really the least important thing.** Those employers who actually value substance will look past the numbers and read the candidates' posts to see how well they explain the solutions they propose and how they handle themselves on the site. For instance, someone with a reputation through the roof but who is constantly abrasive may not be someone who would work well on a team. Conversely, having a modest reputation on SO, but writing well-explained answers and handling corrections or criticism from the community gracefully is nothing to be ashamed of.

**Ultimately, how you handle yourself on SO is more important than the points.** And really this is what you should be focusing on because saying this in public does not help you:

> Given that, I am seriously considering opening 20 accounts (why stop at 2)? If others have an unfair edge over me because of multi account abuse, and bad practice, and nothing gets done about it. As they say, since you cant beat them, join them.

When I read this, what I'm reading is someone threatening sabotage if things do not go their way. No matter how justified you feel, think about how it looks like to a potential employer.

Comment: That's a fair point. Thank you for your feedback. I am constantly working on improving my communication style and learning to be more diplomatic. So that was very much appreciated.